# SQLite3 returns both indexed and associative array

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a SQLite query in PHP:

```
$database = new SQLite3("database.db");
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$result = $statement->execute();
$table = array();
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    array_push($table, $row);
}
var_dump($table);
```

and it outputs

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> int(1)
        ["event"]=> int(1)
        [1]=> string(2) "A1"
        ["code"]=> string(2) "A1"
    }
    [1]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> int(5)
        ["event"]=> int(5)
        [1]=> string(2) "A2"
        ["code"]=> string(2) "A2"
    }
}
```

Which is the correct data, but it's outputting all of the information twice: one with an index attached, and one with the column name. Is there any way to pick one or the other? This program needs to be very memory efficient as it will be expanded to having thousands of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite's [fetchArray](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) function can take a mode parameter. You can use `SQLITE3_ASSOC`, `SQLITE3_NUM`, or `SQLITE3_BOTH` for the desired effect. I guess I should've looked at the documentation before I posted :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a regular mysql-style assoc array output,

```
$db = new SQLite3('dbs');

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

$assoc_array = array();

while ($dbs_row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    $assoc_array[] = $dbs_row;
}
```